# Sharepoint List Items Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, soap

How i can query sharepoint list items using soap in c#?
Code that should query data will be placed on one host (sharepoint 2007, .net 2.0). List located on another host (Sharepoint 2010).
As far as I know, I can not use for this purpose SPSite, SPWeb..

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://hostname/...")) {
  using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) {
     ...
```

Can anyone give me an example of how this can be done?
Tnx!

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To integrate between two different sharepoint instances you have to use the sharepoint web services.

1. In your project create a web reference to the following url: `http://sharepointserver/_vti_bin/lists.asmx`
2. Create a connection to the web service:

   ```
   var client = new SharePointWebServices.Lists { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password") };
   var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   var viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
   viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"ows_FIELD YOU WISH TO RETRIEVE\" />";
   var listGuid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GUID_OF_LIST"];
   XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems(listGuid, null, null, viewFields,
                                                   null, null, null);
   ```
3. Now you have received your collection. simply iterate through the xmlDoc retrieved from the webservice. I do this like this:

   ```
   foreach (XmlNode node in listItems)
   {
      if (node.Name == "rs:data")
      {
         for (int f = 0; f < node.ChildNodes.Count; f++)
         {
            if (node.ChildNodes[f].Name == "z:row")
            {
               var xmlAttributeCollection = node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes;
               if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
               {
                   string listItem = xmlAttributeCollection["ows_ows_FIELD YOU WISH TO RETRIEVE"].Value;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Was this of any help?

Comment: From my experience, `viewFields` can also be `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharePoint soap web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Or if you are getting data from SharePoint 2010 you can use
its [rest api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx).